# Guardar variável binário em modo de lista

Tags: python

Como poderei guardar a variável binário em modo de lista tipo linha horizontal com todos os valores que saem na variável binário.

```
for n in receivedMessage:
    contador += 1
    print (contador)
    binario=list(dec_to_bin(n))# assim sai cada valor na vertical 
    print("RX_Binario: ", binario)
```

Comment: O que é a função `dec_to_bin`? Quais os valores de `n`? Qual o resultado que aparece quando executa o código? Por fim, qual seria o resultado desejado?

Comment: A função dec_to_bin converte o valor decimal de cada caracter de uma string, por exemplo os valores decimais de cada letra desta frase "aeiou" para o seu valor em binário. quando executo o print aparece

Comment: A função dec_to_bin converte o valor decimal de cada caracter de uma string, por exemplo os valores decimais de cada letra desta frase "aeiou" para o seu valor em binário, aquando faço print aparece RX_Binario: ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0','0', '1'] para a letra "a" na linha seguinte RX_Binario: ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1'] para a letra "e" e eu queria por isso tudo na mesma linha e não em linhas separadas, assim RX_Binario ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0','0', '1' ,'1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1']

Comment: Informações referentes à pergunta devem ser adicionadas à pergunta com o [edit].

Comment: Não me deixou editar de novo por fiz um segundo comentario com a resposta á pergunta

Answer (score 1):

Não ficou muito claro se você quer apenas exibir tudo na mesma linha ou armazenar, de fato, em uma mesma lista, visto que está sobrescrevendo o valor de `binario` a cada iteração.

Como, ao meu ver, não faria muito sentido apenas exibir na mesma linha e armazenar de forma separada, irei considerar que deseja também armazenar na mesma lista. Para tal, considerando que o retorno de `dec_to_bin` é uma *string*, que é convertida para uma lista com `list(...)`, então você pode fazer:

```
binario = []

for n in receivedMessage:
    contador += 1
    print (contador)
    binario += list(dec_to_bin(n))

print(binario)
```

Perceba que o `print(binario)` fica fora do laço para imprimir apenas o valor final. As alterações que modificam a lógica são: 1. definir inicialmente `binario` como uma lista vazia e 2. dentro do laço apenas incrementar seu valor utilizando o operador `+=`.

Desta forma, o resultado será parecido com:

```
binario = ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0','0', '1' ,'1', '1', ...]
```

Comment: peço desculpa o que tenho é isto :binario = []

for n in receivedMessage:
    contador += 1
    print (contador)
    binario = list(dec_to_bin(n))

print(binario) e sim o valor final é esse o pretendido

Comment: @SergioNunes Não entendi. É isso mesmo que eu respondi ou entendi errado alguma coisa?

Comment: é isso mesmo, obrigado pela ajuda. Poderei perguntar se poderei perguntar como se pode comparar duas strings  bit a bit da lista do binário? eu tenho um if a fazer a comparação, tenho-o assim : if string!= palavra contador2 += 1 print('numero de erros: ' , contador2) aqui não consigo por o código como deve ser